# Running the stream and batch environment side by side using Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Does it make sense to run stream and batch processing side by side in Flink?

```
//calculate median using DataSet (Batch Environment)
BatchFunctions batch = new BatchFunctions();
DataSet<Tuple2<Double, Integer>> dataSet1 = batch.loadDataSetOfOctober2016();
double median = batch.getMedianReactionTime(dataSet1);

// now use the calculated median in the DataStream (stream environment)
StreamFunctions stream = new StreamFunctions();
DataStream<Tuple7<String, String, Integer, String, Date, String, List<Double>>> dataStream1 = stream.getKafkaStream();
stream.printPredictionForNextReactionTimeByMedians(dataStream1, median, Time.seconds(10));
stream.execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather not to do it.
If your streaming process depends on your batch result. You can get batch result in advance and put in a queue or database table, streaming process can get result from it, so you needn't restart it when batch result changes.
Because streaming process is somewhat infinite. But batch process result may change, because you may run it on different input.